# Having issue with Microsoft Teams access policy, namely New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy command

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When trying to allow applications to access online meetings by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy namely trying exec command:

```
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Test-policy -AppId "my app id"
```

I get

> New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Management.Automation.PSListModifier' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Could you please try to install latest version of [powershell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/3.1.0) and try to re run the cmdlt. Please let us know if it helps

Comment: I've tried run this on PowerShell version 7.2.1 and  5.1.22000.282 with the same result described above

Comment: and about MicrosoftTeams:
The version '3.1.0' of module 'MicrosoftTeams' is currently in use

Comment: Which Application ID you are providing ,? Could you please try to install and run with Version MicrosoftTeams - 2.4.0-preview . Check this doc. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftTeams/2.4.0-preview

Comment: Id "269aca65-06e1-4805-a778-..." of my application from Azure portal for what I want to create an access policy

Comment: Unfortunately command
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -RequiredVersion 2.4.0-preview -AllowPrerelease
doesn't overwrite actual 3.1.0 version - It would be great if you could help me replace actual version
On the other hand actually, I can't realize why I need to install old prerelease version to resolve the problem - it's a bit weird approach

Comment: As per the given document the current version is 2.4.0 preview . So to install uninstall the current version and try to install and try with it

Answer (score 1):

It should be AppsID**s** with a final **s** and please add a description:

```
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Test-policy -AppIds "my app id" -Description "Some description"
```

[Create a new application access policy with one app ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/new-csapplicationaccesspolicy?view=skype-ps#create-a-new-application-access-policy-with-one-app-id)

Comment: It's no difference - AppId is also correct syntax for only id.
In addition I tried using -AppIds, with -Description, etc.

Comment: In case of using incorrect syntax PowerShell just displays a notification about that and doesn't let you send requests

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think the problem here is, that his code is not only that 1 line and @966647 maybe is trying to pass the appid from a earlier get?

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Test-policy -AppId $(get-azureadapplication | Where-Object DisplayName -eq "TestApp")

New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' to type 'System.String'.